# Laravel Nova custom login

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

My Laravel project uses the following user types: students, parents, trainers. Now I would like to use Laravel Nova for the backend to manage the different resources.

Nova uses the *users* table, and model as default, however, I would like to use the *admins* table and model for the login.

I already created a custom *admins* table and model and updated the `config/auth.php`.

*database/migrations/create_admins_table.php*

```php
...
public function up()
{
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name', 60);
            $table->string('email', 60)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
}
```

*config/auth.php*

```php
'guards' => [

        ...

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [

        ...

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
    ],
```

**What changes do I have to make to use the admins' table/guard for the Nova login?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `/config` folder, you'll find the file `nova.php`. Inside it, change the following line of code to specify your guard. For example:

`'guard' => 'admins',`

Comment: I already did that! Do I have to change something in the `/Nova/User.php` File?

Comment: Your question mentions that you changed "config/auth.php" but did you also change "config/nova.php"?